# Apache POI class loading issues

Tags: apache-poi

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.DocumentDocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:136)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:166)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:118)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.<init>(XWPFWordExtractor.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(ExtractorFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:87)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    ... 22 more
```

**JARS USED:**

```
poi-ooxml-3.12.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar
poi-3.12.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.12.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

Solution Needed..for this issue.

> This error throws only for docx files.

Comment: Do you have any other Apache POI jars on your classpath? At first glance, it looks like you have an older `poi-ooxml-schemas` or `ooxml-schemas` jar on the classpath confusing things

Comment: No.I have only list of jars i mentioned in my classpath.I have 3.12 version jars which was downloaded at apache site.It was actually class locale which was throwing this exception.It returns documentImpl instance instead of document instance.I also tried maven to see if i have missed any jar dependencies.But i was not wrong.I have all jars correctly placed.

Comment: In what context is this running? Is this a Web-Application? Or an OSGi bundled application? Your error could also be caused by a mixup of classes due to an environment where classloaders are handled in a special way.

Comment: Yes it is an OSGi bundled application.Basically am using Knime tool.

Comment: Try use `ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar` instead of `poi-ooxml-3.12.jar`. Also check the latest poi version.

Comment: I have tried it.No luck on that too.I removed poi-ooxml-3.12.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar and added ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar.Also tried with both ooxml-schemas jars